# Milliseconds from DateTime in SQL Server and C# are not the same

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm getting dates from a database in SQL Server.
When I get the `DateTime` from the DB and I compare the milliseconds in C# and SQL Server.
I see that they are not the same.

Why is that?

Comment: Could you show an example of what you see?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server's `datetime` data type is not accurate at the milliseconds level.
[Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) provides a list of properties of the data time data type.
In that list, you will find the following row:

> `Accuracy     Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds`

You will also find, in that same page, the following quote:

> **Note**
>   Use the **time**, **date**, **datetime2** and **datetimeoffset** data types for new work. These types align with the SQL Standard. They are more portable. **time**, **datetime2** and **datetimeoffset** provide more seconds precision. **datetimeoffset** provides time zone support for globally deployed applications.

If you would work with [`DateTime2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) isntead of `DateTime`, you would get 100 nanoseconds accuracy, among other benefits.
In fact, except in cases when you need to maintain backwards compatibility, you should not work with `DateTime` at all, only with the newer data types.